# King David accepts God's will by touching the Ark

Tags: david

Did David lay hands on the Ark of the Testimony? (depicted in the 1951 movie "David and Bathsheba" with Gregory Peck)

Comment: Are you asking whether Christians believe that was something that really happened?

Comment: This question is unclear.

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about the question. Seems clear to me.

Comment: Know where I can watch the movie? Kind of outside of my regular library.

Answer (score 2):

If he did, its nowhere stated in the Bible.  Rather, the Bible clearly states that anyone who is not a priest will die if they touch the ark.   In 2nd Samuel 6 and 1st Chronicles 13 the story is told of how when David decided to have the ark brought back from Gibeah to Jerusalem, and contrary to the Torah, David had the ark placed on a cart (rather than carried by the priests using the staves as the Law says in Exodus 25 and Numbers 7:9), the oxen shook the cart, and a man by the name of Uzzah touched it and died.